# Codeigniter flash data not working in certain browsers

Tags: codeigniter

I’m having some issues with Codeigniter flashdata.  Everything seems to be working in Firefox, but in Chrome (and my mobile BB browser, FWIW) it seems as if no flashdata is persisting between pages.  I should note also that everything is ok when I work locally, even in Chrome.  But on the production site in chrome, flashdata doesn’t persist.

I’ve spent the better part of the evening researching the issue, but no other threads/ideas seem to do the trick.  There are no 404s that could be interfering.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it! There was some weird stuff going on with certain browsers looking for our favicon in such a way that our MY_controller was being called twice on every request (i.e. the browser's looking for our favicon was being interpreted as an action call). Very strange stuff, took forever to debug and figure it out but very gratifying once I did. Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same sort of issue.

Comment: How did you fix the  favicon problem?

Comment: Make sure you actually have a favicon file (favicon.ico) in your top level directory, and if you have rewrite rules in your htaccess include an appropriate condition on favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter flash data are associated with session and also, will be available to the next server request, So it shouldnt matter about whether chrome or Firefox. Well, are you using any CSS styles for the flash data?

Comment: I've been working with CI a lot so I'm very familiar with how flashdata works and how to use it.  Styles have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see ur reply, So did you fix the problem..? Or still the same?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with Firefox, realized later on that Firefox was reloading the page because: The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file.

Make sure the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` is with in the first 1024 bytes of the view file being loaded.