# CodeIgniter Flashdata doesn't work on server

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter's flashdata to store my captcha word for the next request. It works fine on the local site, but not on the server. There is no difference between the two codes.

I'm wondering wether the flashdata feature requires any additional plugin or configuration for apache/php.

Here's how I set the data:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('captchaWord', $cap['word']);
```

and this is how I retrieve it:

```
if (strcasecmp($this->input->post('captchaWord'), $this->session->flashdata('captchaWord')) != 0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: flashdata requires using the session library - which is either saved in the database or a cookie (based on the value in your config file). There shouldn't be anything that apache or php is missing for this to work. Either you have issues writing to the database, or maybe security issues creating data in a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. Something strange is going on with your server.

Check that that a database connection is being made if you're using database sessions.

Check that what you're redirecting to is actually the same server.

Check that you're using flashdata correctly. (Post code?)

Check that session variables are working at all.

Update:

```
// Again, be sure that 'session' is autoloaded in config.php
class Test_Controller {
    public function page1()
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('test', 'HELLO WORLD');
        redirect('test/page2');
    }
    public function page2()
    {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('test');
    }
}
```

Add this controller and visit http://yourserver.com/index.php/test/page1

It should redirect to page2 and display 'HELLO WORLD'.

If it does, then it's a problem with your code. If it doesn't, then I would suggest loading up a virtual machine with an OS and installing a new copy of a webserver and trying again.

Comment: No database, no secure sessions. Other session variables are working. I updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Codeigniter is calling a controller twice, in which case it is clearing the flashdata between the first and second calls (See an answer to [Codeigniter flash data not working in certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147646/codeigniter-flash-data-not-working-in-certain-browsers)).

There are Codeigniter cases where a controller may be called twice. For example, the GoCart shopping cart package, built on Codeigniter, has a helper function to force SSL by changing http to https and doing a redirect to the new URL. If the function is used in the constructor, the controller ends up being called twice, once without and once with SSL. Any flashdata is lost with the second call.

Per another similar question ([CodeIgniter: setting flash data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378702/codeigniter-setting-flash-data-not-working)), you can use $CI->session->keep_flashdata() to preserve flashdata across additional requests.

The answer on this page does a good job of explaining the issue and the workaround: [CodeIgniter "flashdata" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work)