# CodeIgniter: setting flash data not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using the following code to manage pagination in search results:

```
if ($this->input->post('search-notes') && (is_string($this->input->post('search-notes')) || is_string($this->input->post('search-notes')))):
    $this->session->set_flashdata('search-notes', $_POST['search-notes']);
    $post['search-notes'] = $this->input->post('search-notes');
elseif ($this->session->flashdata('search-notes')):
    $this->session->set_flashdata('search-notes', $this->session->flashdata('search-notes'));
    $post['search-notes'] = $this->session->flashdata('search-notes');
endif;
if (isset($post['search-notes']) && is_string($post['search-notes']) && !empty($post['search-notes'])):
...
```

All of which works fine on my development computer, but chokes on the live website; the final `if()` statement does not evaluate to true.

However, if I echo out the `$post['search-notes']` variable either before or within the final `if()` statement, it works!

It's utterly bizarre, and I've never encountered anything like it before.

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0

On a side note, the original title had much more specificity: "Problem with `set_flashdata()` function in CodeIgniter". But due to some excitable and excessive moderation rules, I've had to water it down to something less meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should attend is once you call `$this->session->flashdata('search-notes')` method, it unsets the `'search-notes'` item from session.

So, when you check the `$this->session->flashdata('search-notes')` at the second time, `'search-notes'` will no longer exists.

If you want to keep the item in session, use [`set_userdata()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L459) and [`userdata()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L431) instead.

Also, you can use `keep_flashdata('search-notes')` **after** `set_flashdata()` **or** before the first call of `flashdata()` to preserve the flashdata variable through an additional request.

**As a side point:**
There's no need to check `isset()` and `!empty()` together. `empty()` [does NOT generate a warning if the variable does not exist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), and returns `FALSE`.

*[CI reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)*

There is also a nice [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/) on nettuts+ could be useful.

---

**Jus as a Demo:**
*do NOT copy, check the logic.*

```php
if ($_POST['search-notes'] AND is_string($_POST['search-notes']))
{
    $post['search-notes'] = $this->input->post('search-notes'/*, TRUE*/ /* Enable XSS filtering */);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('search-notes', $post['search-notes']);
}
elseif ($searchNotes = $this->session->flashdata('search-notes'))
{
    $post['search-notes'] = $searchNotes;
}

if (! empty($post['search-notes']) AND is_string($post['search-notes'])):
// ...
```

If you need to keep the `search-notes` item in session, use the following at the first `if` statement:

```php
if ($_POST['search-notes'] AND is_string($_POST['search-notes']))
{
    $post['search-notes'] = $this->input->post('search-notes'/*, TRUE*/ /* Enable XSS filtering */);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('search-notes', $post['search-notes']);
    // Keep the flashdata through an additional request
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('search-notes');

} // ...
```

Comment: Hashem, thanks for the effort, but it doesn't make any difference. Also, there's an error on the final if() statement as a result of the $post['search-notes'] not evaluating. But — and as I stated earlier — if I echo that variable, it evaluates. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: could you write `var_dump($post['search-notes']);` after the final `if` and post the result?

Comment: Okay, I tried the set_userdata() and userdata() functions and they're working. Hashem, thanks.