# CodeIgniter Flashdata and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm running out of things to try, hopefully there's something obvious I'm overlooking :)

I have a single controller website with 3 functions. One for the actual view, and 2 for ajax requests.

This is for a two-part form. So the first ajax request creates the DB entry and populates it with the data from the first part of the form, the second ajax request takes some follow up information and updates the db entry with that data.

This all happens on a single page.

So something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('entries');
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('entry');
}

public function index()
{   
    $this->load->view('home');
}

public function ajax_one()
{
    // Validation etc.

    $id = $this->entries->insert_entry();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('entry', $id);

    $this->load->view('ajax_home');
}

public function ajax_two()
{
    // Validation etc.

    $this->entries->finish_entry( $this->session->flashdata('entry') );

    $this->load->view('ajax_home');
}
```

As you can see the first ajax page gets the id from the db entry and stores it in flashdata, with the idea that the second ajax query updates the same db entry by passing in the id via the flashdata. The problem is that the flashdata is returning blank in the second request, even using 'keep_flashdata'.

I have no idea how else to approach this. I can't populate a hidden field anywhere on the page because it doesn't reload at any point during the process, so there's no mechanism for me to get the variable data out of the first ajax function and into the second.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you pass the ID back form the first ajax response in a JSON object?  then you can send it as a param with the second AJAX request..?

Comment: Hm, not a bad idea that. It means rewriting some of the logic on the javascript side… but I can at least see that working! Shame I can't keep it all in the controller though, much neater.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really a fan of CI sessions at all, I think they are quite tempremental and have issues with them constantly, but if your CI session config is set to use cookies, then I'm not sure this method will work for AJAX requests.. double check and set it to use DB sessions if its not already.  Otherwise, make sure your first page response is returning a session ID cookie for both AJAX requests to use.

Comment: Do regular CI sessions work?

Comment: Yea I haven't had any issues with sessions - I think must be because of the kind of requests, maybe they're not registering properly and so the flashdata is never really available. I've just gone down the json route though and got it working - this isn't a form that needs to be particular secure so I'm not too worried about DOM hacking, and I can always use the encryption class to get around that anyway. I'll likely form this into a solution once I'm confident this is the best method. Thanks @RaggaMuffin-420

Comment: yeah, for a little more security i'd be tempted to set a random hash against the record as well for cross referencing, so any DOM hack would have to guess both the ID and the corresponding hash value.

Comment: @NathanHornby You should use the `keep_flashdata()` method after setting the flashdata variable by `set_flashdata()` or before the first call of `flashdata()`. Further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378702/codeigniter-setting-flash-data-not-working/17379927#17379927